# Why Django DoesNotExist Erase other objects?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm facing an issue with Django and specially the use of DoesNotExist.

In my script, I'm trying to check if '**Scraper**' object exist or not, if it doesn't the object is created.

For checking if it exist or not i'm using a 'try catch Model.DoesNotExists', .get() with two parameters the first one is an IDs and the last the User object.

The issue is rising when two **Scraper** object has a same ids but different user's, the first one '**Scraper**' is created and the second erase the first one.

```
try:
    a = Scraper.objects.get(id_lbc=ids, user=user)
except Scraper.DoesNotExist:
    a = Scraper(
        id_lbc=ids,
        lbc_name=title,
        lbc_url=url,
        lbc_image=image,
        lbc_price=price,
        lbc_date=date,
        lbc_city=city,
        lbc_price_meter=price_meter,
        user=user,
        token_url=token,
        customer=customer,
        has_phone=phone,
    )
    a.save()
```

Model

```
class Scraper(models.Model):
    id_lbc = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    lbc_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    lbc_url = models.URLField(max_length=300)
    lbc_image = models.URLField(
        max_length=300, default='http://****/****/nothing.jpg')
    lbc_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lbc_price_meter = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    lbc_city = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    lbc_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token_url = models.ForeignKey(
        Url_lbc, to_field='token', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_emailed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    has_phone = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lbc_name
```

What I want is create two **Scraper** object with same 'ids' but different User's
for example

**Scraper** N°1
ids = 1234567
user = Nico(object)

**Scraper** N°2
ids = 1234567
user = Paul(object)

I thought with the User object given, the Django query can see the difference between two **Scraper** object but I misunderstood something...maybe the PK in my model ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want with your current model design. This is because `id_lbc` is set as a primary key. This means it has to be unique, you can't have two istances sharing that value. What you could do though is:

```
class Scraper(models.Model):
    id_lbc = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('user', 'id_lbc')]
```

This will make it such that `id_lbc` can have duplicates within the table as long as each value has a different `user` value.

Then you should also use `Scraper.objects.get_or_create`:

```
a, created = Scraper.objects.get_or_create(id_lbc=ids, user=user, defaults={
    'lbc_name': title,
    'lbc_url': url,
    'lbc_image': image,
    'lbc_price': price,
    'lbc_date': date,
    'lbc_city': city,
    'lbc_price_meter': price_meter,
    'token_url': token,
    'customer': customer,
    'has_phone': phone,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `Scraper` directly to create the object, call instead `Scraper.objects.create(...)`